# AWS Amplify - Ignoring certain folders inside API src folder

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am testing my express API locally by installing node modules and running the server from within the API's amplify folder.  It works great, my webapp connects to it and I can build my front-end.

How can I have the Amplify CLI ignore this folder when comparing the local changes to the deployed backend? Once I install the node_modules folder it considers the API to be changed so it would try to re-build it.

The node modules installation folder that needs to be ignored by Amplify CLI:
amplify/backend/function/nodeapi/src/node_modules

Is it possible?